# How to overlay a ViewPager with another ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two `ViewPager`s - one below the other. Now the client wants us to add the possibility to expand the bottom `ViewPager` (with three `ListView`s) to overlay the top `ViewPager`. When I put both `ViewPager`s in a `ScrollView` the `ListView`s in the bottom `ViewPager` stopped working. At first I put them in a `RelativeLayout` and added top padding to all `ListView`s and set the background to `null`, but then the top `ViewPager` was not clickable (albeit visible). How can I get this working?

[image]

Comment: What user action does the red arrow signify? Is it "scrolling while the end of the bottom `ListView` has been reached"? Or would any scrolling-up push out the top `ViewPager`?

Comment: And is it "all or nothing" for the top `ViewPager`? Or do you want it to show partially when it is not fully scrolled out or in?

Comment: Start of scrolling-up should push out the top ViewPager or cover it. I want to show him partially when moving up or being covered by bottom ViewPager.

Comment: Okay, and I assume that there should be a red arrow on the left and the right columns in the second picture, too. That is to say that if the top `ViewPager` is pushed out of view, it cannot be brought back by swiping left or right (only by scrolling down).

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated and I may be missing some of the steps, but essentially what you have to do is the following:

- Put the two `ViewPager`s in a `LinearLayout`. While the parent will match its parent in height, the children will be wrapped.
- Implement the `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` and set the `OnScrollListener` of your three `ListView` s to this implementation.
- In this implementation (either in `onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)` or in `onScroll(final AbsListView listView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)` you'll have to figure this one out yourself) get the delta of the current and the old scroll position - get the distance and the direction (the correct sign, essentially) of the scroll.
- Change the y coordinate of your two `ViewPager`s accordingly, controlling for edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looked very interesting and I've added a [project at Github](https://github.com/comeondude/NestedScrollViewWithViewPagerAndRecyclerView) trying to solve the problem myself. You can clone the project and run to see what happens.

The idea is to have two `ViewPager` inside a `NestedScrollView` and the `ViewPager` at the bottom containing a `RecyclerView`.

You need to keep it in mind that it will only work with `RecyclerView 23.2.0` and up. So you need to add the following in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

While `NestedScrollView` serves the purpose, it generates some unwanted behaviour too. For example, the list in the bottom `ViewPager` scrolls to bottom automatically when the list is populated. So I had to add the following inside my `MainActivity`

```
mNestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

You need to handle the proper scrolling here when the fragments are swiped in the `ViewPager` every time. I've added `onPageChangeListener` with both of the `ViewPager` and added comments there too.

Another thing you need to keep in mind that in the main layout file which is `activity_main.xml`, I had to keep the height of both `ViewPager` to be fixed. You might consider changing the `layout_height` as per your requirement.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using BottomSheet in tandem with Coordinator Layout:

- Your Bottom fragment can sit in the BottomSheet while Top Fragment will be in the Coordinator Layout
- The scrolling will be handled by BottomSheet.

https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/